# Python : Problem using google AIY and Google TextToSpeech

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, google-aiy

I'm having an issue with python and my AIY voice kit on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

I can get the AIY voice kit to work, recognise trigger words and all.
I can also get google's TextToSpeech API working no problem with text or ssml.

However I can't get both of them to work in the same programme.
AIY uses python3 and TextToSpeech doesn't, so whether I run the command with "python" or "python3" I get a "Cannot import name ...."

Running it with python3 sends a "cannot import name texttospeech" and with python, it sends a "cannot import name aiy"

Any Ideas on how can I get round this?

Thanks everyone

Comment: try to install text to speech with pip3

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked a charm. I can't believe it was so simple (or that I was so daft).